# Any one knows how to write a async ajax test by jasmine 2.0

Tags: javascript, ajax, testing, jasmine

I want to write a function test, in order to test the json data from the server side,however i have no idea how to write the test, i search the google but still have no idea.

Here is my [code link](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonzhang/Lr727/)

```
//Controller
'use strict';
app.controller('TuserInterface',function ($scope,dataloginRegister,$http) {

var loginRegisterService = dataloginRegister;

$scope.doLogin = loginRegisterService.doLogin('username','password').then(function(data){
    $scope.test_1 = data;
    console.log($scope.test_1); //it's work can get json data from the server side
    });
});

//service
'use strict';
angular.module('loginservice',[
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
    ]).
    factory('dataloginRegister',['$http','$log',function($http,$log){
        var urlBase = 'http://example.com:8080/user-common-controller/common/';
        var dataloginRegister = {};
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01';

        dataloginRegister.doLogin = function(username,password ){
            return $http.post(urlBase+"user/login",
                    $.param({"username":username,"password":password,})
                     );          
        };
    });
//how to write the test code , not mock by js , just test the json data form the server side
```

Test code:

```
'use strict';
describe('Controller: TuserInterface', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('bogouLoginApp')); 
  var TuserInterface,
    scope;   
  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();  
    TuserInterface = $controller('TuserInterface', {
      $scope: scope,       
    });

  }));   
  it('test json data from server',function(){
      expect(xxx.length).toBe(??);
   });                                 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your spec (the 'it' function also provide the `done` parameter:

```
it('test json data from server',function(done){
  expect(xxx.length).toBe(??);
});
```

Then pass that `done` reference to your callback and issue it to signal Jasmine that it can end the rest.
See [this link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html%20this%20link) for more details.